# PHP upload to certain folder based on HTML checkbox

Tags: php, html, upload

Im new to PHP and still learning, but I want to know if I am able to do something like this. I have a basic HTML form like the one below.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cb" value="checkb">Make Private.</label>
</form>
```

And a basic upload PHP document like the one below as well.

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        header('Location: /');
    }else {
        echo "Original Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        $randprefix = hash('ripemd160', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32), false);
        $filepath = "upload/" . $randprefix . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        if (file_exists($filepath)) {
            echo $filepath . " already exists. ";
        }else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filepath);
            echo "Link to file: " . '<a href = "' . $filepath . '">' . $filepath . '</a>' ;

        }
    }
}else {
    echo "File too large.";
}
?>
```

What i'm asking is, is it possible to have a checkbox on the HTML form that when checked the file will upload to a folder named "private" and when unchecked the file will upload to a folder named "public". Thank you.

Comment: YES! But not automagically. You have to code a test and then `move_uploaded_files()` to the right place

Comment: Good code indexntation aids in reading and more importantly **debugging**

Comment: @GrizPwnz. Provided my code with an **explanation** too so that it will be useful for the other who needs the same help to. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the condition like this so that than only you can get the checkbox value after the form is submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['check']))
{
    $filepath = "upload/private" . $randprefix . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
else
{
    $filepath = "upload/public" . $randprefix . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
```

> You have to place the **name for the checkbox input type** so that you can check in the upload.php page and then set the folder over there.

Replace:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cb" value="checkb">Make Private.</label>
```

With:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cb" value="checkb" name="check">Make Private.</label>
```

**Explanation:** When the user selects the checkbox at the time of submitting it will check for the check box value and it will make the `$filepath` as `upload/private` or else if the user while submitting the data he/she has not selected the check box it will change the code as per the selection if the check box value. So that you can `move_upload_file()` based on the selection available.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul. Code updated with the `isset()` function fr checking purpose.

Comment: Great! We should delete our comments now.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @GrizPwnz. If you find it useful you can accept it as the correct one since if the same error occurs for the other developers too it will be useful for them to rectify it based on the code that i have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="checkb" value="checkb">Make Private.</label>
</form>
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
{
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
    header('Location: /');
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Original Name: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    $randprefix = hash('ripemd160', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32), false);
    if($_POST['checkb'] == "checkb")
    {
      $filepath = "private/" . $randprefix . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    else
    {
      $filepath = "upload/" . $randprefix . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    if (file_exists($filepath))
    {
      echo $filepath . " already exists. ";
    }
else
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filepath);
  echo "Link to file: " . '<a href = "' . $filepath . '">' . $filepath . '</a>' ;

    }
  }
}
else
{
  echo "File too large.";
}
?>
```

I think it is work I test It and you haven`t problems to copy!